# How to use non stable features of Openlayers 3?

Tags: version, openlayers-3, translate

I need to use some features of the development version of OpenLayers 3 (non stable), namelly the translate method of ol.geom. It is possible to test and use these in my aplication? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the relative code for the application in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "experimental" features of an OpenLayers 3 release in the same way that you use the stable features.  Both experimental and stable features are available to [custom builds](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/doc/tutorials/custom-builds.html) or a full build of the library.

It is important to keep in mind that experimental features may be changed or removed in future releases.  However, it is also common that experimental features are promoted to stable features in future releases.

In the case of the [`geometry.translate()`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.geom.SimpleGeometry.html?stableonly=true#translate) method, this was released as stable [in 3.5.0](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/commit/d79abe7448e6505ae3c38888992dcc30610c42b9) (so it will remain that way for all future 3.x releases).

Comment: Many thanks, Tim, that's exactly what I needed. Congratulations and thanks for your great work